# Separate a column into two columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007. I have a column in my Excel spreadsheet. It contains data that should be separated into two columns. In this column, some rows are dates. Some are email addresses. Some are empty.

I want to import the data via SSIS into a SQL table. I think the best way is to create a date column and an email column. Where the row is empty or an email address, the date for that row will be null. Where the row is empty or a date, the email for that row will be null. The date column will need to be date format for the SSIS import. The email column needs to be text format.

How do I do this?

Comment: This question is probably off topic (unless you are writing some kind of script that runs in Excel), and even if it is on topic you should really show us something you've tried and explain what it is doing that you don't expect to fit the SO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data starts in Row1 of ColumnA then:

in `B1`: `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,"")` and
in `C1`: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("@",A1)>0,A1,""),"")`

and copied down to suit should split the source into columns by type.